# Datatable dynamic data not available from apollo graphql query (static works)

Tags: vue.js, datatable, graphql, apollo, quasar-framework

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
  name: 'patient-list',
  data () {
    return {
      patients: [],
      patientsColumns: [
        { name: 'id', label: 'number', field: 'patient_number' },
        { name: 'last', label: 'last name', field: row => row.user.last },
        { name: 'first', label: 'first name', field: row => row.user.first }
      ]
    }
  },
  apollo: {
    patients: {
      query: gql`
         {
         patients {
           patient_number
           user {
             first
             last
           }
         }
        }
      `
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <div>
    {{patients[0]}}
    <q-table
      :data="patients"
      :columns="patientsColumns"
      row-key="name"
    ></q-table>
  </div>
```

I have problem with printing datas in table by apollo... and i can't figure out what is wrong with this :) 
the main problem with my console is 
( TypeError: Cannot add property __index, object is not extensible )

I created sample static data and was ok, but when I what use datas passed from apollo by graphql query datatable show "no data available"

If someone give me small advice I will be grateful :)

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot add property __index, object is
>   not extensible"

Datatable and sample record passed from Graphql by apollo

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB2d1.png)

[Printed first object from apollo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvLSK.png)

[ERRORS FROM CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbxe6.png)

Comment: Apollo 3 freezes the data object.